# Should I store my refresh token in database?

Tags: jwt

I have a website in node js and react js. Whenever a user signIn on my website, they recieve a refresh token which is stored in an httpOnly cookie and an access token which is stored in the memory. When the access token expires I sent the refresh token in the request to get a new access token but I cannot understand where to store the refresh token. Should store it in my database because once the httpOnly cookie expires, there will be no way to get that back. So should I store it in the user object or in an array where all the referesh tokens are saved and whenever a request for new access token comes, I find the refresh token in that array and if it exists, I give them new access token.
Please suggest a safe way

Answer (score 0):

It's better to store a refresh token locally. If the database would get hacked, the hacker would have unlimited access to the accounts using the refresh tokens. For more information, check out [this post on Stack Overflow](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/194774/how-to-handle-refresh-tokens)

Answer (score 0):

Both `access_token` and `refresh_token` is stored on client end. This client end either could be browser or system (invoking the apis). For browser, you can store the refresh token in local storage or in other available options. For external systems, it could be secure storage which can be a database.